# Reshape function is not working for multiclass classification for LSTM

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm, reshape, multiclass-classification

My code for passing data to LSTM,

```
Xres1.shape
(291676, 15)

yres1.shape
(291676,)

n_samples, n_feats = Xres1.shape[0], Xres1.shape[1]

Xres1 = Xres1.reshape((n_samples, n_feats, 1))

yres1 = to_categorical(yres1, 4)

model = Sequential()

model.add(LSTM(n_feats, input_shape=(n_feats, 1)))

model.add(Dense(20))

model.add(Dense(60))

model.add(Dense(80))

model.add(Dense(90))

model.add(Dense(4, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')

model.fit(Xres1, yres1, epochs=300, batch_size=15, verbose=2)
```

> AttributeError: DataFrame object has no attribute reshape

Sometimes the reshape function is working and sometimes not.

Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

`Pandas-Dataframe` doesn’t have built in reshape function. Use `.values` to reshape the Dataframe

```
Xres1 = Xres1.values.reshape((n_samples, n_feats, 1))
```